# JQUery find and match parent based on a dynamic child class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Ok it's a little hard to explain in a single title but basically I have a dynamic class added to a child element based on it's parent's dynamic class. Added so:

```
$('ul').each(function(key){
    if ($(this).hasClass('sortable')){
        $(this).addClass('parent' + key);
        $(this).children().addClass('parent' + key);
    };
});
```

The structure is pretty simple after this:

```
<ul class="parent0">
    <li class="parent0">
        <ul class="parent1">
            <li class="parent1"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now the UI has the user move these li outside of the parent and placed elsewhere. Later on, I want to check the element and then match it to it's corresponding (original) parent. It can't be $(this) parent because it will be moved out of the parent but the classes still remain.

So the check is looking for .parent(n) and then finding the ul with .parent(n) eventually this code will live inside:

```
$('sortable li').appendTo($('THIS-IS-THE-DYNAMIC-CLASS'));
```

So I'm assuming the find will be before this but I don't know how to write that.

Comment: It would probably be better to use data attributes and ids for this. Give the uls ids `id="parent0"`, and the lis would have something like `data-parent="parent0"`.

Comment: as it stands, you should be able to do something like this `$('.sortable li').each(function(){$(this).appendTo($("ul." + this.className));});`

Comment: I thought about ids but was thinking of reusable code as well. Right now, none of the ul or li have any ids so it would be ok but if I were to reuse this later, the elements might have ids already or need ids etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a different attribute other than class so it can be wholly unique.  Either use `$(this).data` or `$(this).attr`.  And I would recommend assigning IDs to the parent (or a different attribute) that, again, can be wholly unique.  This will keep things cleaner in my opinion.

For example...

Assuming:

```
$(this).attr('parentClass', '.parent' + key);
```

then

```
$('.sortable li').each(function() { $(this).appendTo($(this).attr('parentClass')); });
```

Comment: I would suggest changing the `parentClass` attribute to be more explicit `'ul.parent' + key`

Comment: This works perfectly. Would you suggest I use the .data or .attr or is that really just a preference? Thanks for the help. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: I might go with data since the attribute doesn't have any real markup value.  But in a pinch, when debugging, attr will be visible to the browser.  And attributes will "clone" if you copy the markup of one element to another.  But purists will say that the attribute you give is invalid (i.e. not in the schema).  So, pros and cons to both.  If I were creating this, I'd probably use whichever my fingers decided to type at that time and not think about it any more than that :)